# SQL*Plus, @, and relative paths

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, scripting

Somehow, it seems that SQL*Plus (at least on Windows) is unable to locate a script with a relative path when called with `@@` and when the path starts with a single or double dot.

For example, under `x:\some\where` I have the following directory structure:

```
script.sql
main-dir\main-sub-dir
              call-script.sql
              script.sql
```

That is: two `script.sql` but at different locations.

The content of `script.sql` just under `x:\some\where` is simply

```
prompt SCRIPT root
```

while the other `script.sql`'s content is

```
prompt SCRIPT main-dir/main-subdir
```

`call-script.sql` reads

```
@@script.sql
@ script.sql
```

## expected output

If I start SQL*Plus from `x:\some\where` and then do a

```
@main-dir/main-sub-dir/call-scripts
```

The output will be

```
SCRIPT main-dir/main-subdir
SCRIPT root
```

This is expected, since the single `@` is supposed to search paths from where SQL*Plus was started and `@@` is supposed to search paths from the containing script's directory.

## unexpected output

*Now*, if I change `call-scripts.sql` so:

```
@@./script.sql
@ ./script.sql
```

the double `@@` seems to change it's behaviour, in that it searches paths from where SQL*Plus was started, and the output will now be

```
SCRIPT root
SCRIPT root
```

which is *not* what I expected.

---

Is this behaviour documented somewhere, and more importantly, how do I have to change `call-scripts.sql` so that it calls relative paths (`@@../../other-dir/other-sub-dir/script`) correctly?

Comment: What's your SQLPATH environment variable set to? That affects which directories are searched.

Comment: By the way, the docs are here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve003.htm#i2696759 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve002.htm#i2696724

Comment: Same behaviour under Linux, FWIW. (And an ampersand is &, not @; which [doesn't seem to have a real name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign)). Seems to be bug, since it's inconsistent. Only thing that comes to mind is to set a variable it the top level script with the full path and do everything based on that, but that's not very convenient unless the directory structure below that is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the *@ vs ampersands* thing... I should have known it, but when I wrote the post I didn't really pay attention. It's now fixed in the title.

Comment: I just attacked sqlplus with `strace`. Here's the relevant calls: http://pastebin.com/cVK1QQu4 Note that it didn't attempt to stat or access "script.sql" files in any other directories before attempting to open the ones seen in the pastebin output.

Comment: @Phil: thanks for stracing the `open()` calls. It seems to confirm that the this behaviour is by design (aka feature, not bug)

Comment: No worries. Was more intrigued than anything else. I hate mysteries ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup, this is Bug 2391334 which has been around for long time, and probably will not be fixed in the near future.

One way of working around this is "know" the path for scripts *without* actually hard coding that path.  To do this in SQLPlus requires a trick - if you try to run a non-existent file, then you'll get an error message that includes the path name.

So here's a demo of that in action.  To mimic your scenario I've got:

```
c:\temp\demo
   script.sql
   maindir
      subdir
         call_script.sql
         script.sql
```

What we can do is add some commands to the front of call_script.sql which will pick up the path.  It looks a little odd, but you should not need to change it - its just a fixed thing you paste in

```
set termout off
spool _path_finder.sql
@@_nonexistent_script.sql
spool off;

var path varchar2(100);
set serverout on
declare
  output varchar2(1000) := regexp_replace(replace(q'{
@_path_finder.sql
}',chr(10)),'.*"(.*)".*','\1');
begin 
  :path:=substr(output,1,length(output)-24);
end;
/
col path new_val path
select :path path from dual;
set termout on
```

What's happening here, is we're running a non-existent script, which returns:

"SP2-0310: unable to open file "path\_nonexistent_script.sql"

so with a little regexp we can extract the path, store it in a SQLPlus variable and then use from that point on.

So the final version of your call_script.sql would look like this

```
set termout off
spool _path_finder.sql
@@_nonexistent_script.sql
spool off;

var path varchar2(100);
set serverout on
declare
  output varchar2(1000) := regexp_replace(replace(q'{
@_path_finder.sql
}',chr(10)),'.*"(.*)".*','\1');
begin 
  :path:=substr(output,1,length(output)-24);
end;
/
col path new_val path
select :path path from dual;
set termout on
prompt path was &path      

@@&path\script.sql
@&path\script.sql
```

and when we run that, we get the following

```
SQL> @maindir\mainsubdir\call_script
path was maindir\mainsubdir
script in subdir
script in subdir
```

and there you go :-)